# orgmode - use constants in org table formula

Tags: org-mode

Below code doesn't work:

```
#+CONSTANTS: t=2
| A      | B |
|--------+---|
| #ERROR | 1 |
| #ERROR | 2 |
| #ERROR | 3 |
#+TBLFM: $1=$t*$2
```

But I wish the output is:

```
#+CONSTANTS: t=2
| A | B |
|---+---|
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
#+TBLFM: $1=$t*$2
```

Comment: Did you `C-c C-c` on the CONSTANTS declaration first? You need to do that to [activate any changes](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html) on in-buffer settings.

Comment: exactly, after C-c C-c on the CONSTANTS firstly, it works fine now! Thanks

Comment: This is a common enough mistake that it seems worthwhile to add it as an answer and have it accepted for the sake of future readers.